# fastest starts with search algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search

I need to implement a search algorithm which only searches from the start of the string rather than anywhere within the string.

I am new to algorithms but from what I can see it seems as though they go through the string and find any occurrence.

I have a collection of strings (over 1 million) which need to be searched everytime the user types a keystroke.

EDIT:

This will be an incremental search. I currently have it implemented with the following code and my searches are coming back ranging between 300-700ms from over 1 million possible strings. The collection isnt ordered but there is no reason it couldnt be.

```
private ICollection<string> SearchCities(string searchString) {
        return _cityDataSource.AsParallel().Where(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith(searchString)).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: So you want to find all strings in a set such that your input string is a prefix of them? You should look at [String.startsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383988.aspx). You should also post an attempt at it yourself, and we'll point out mistakes, guide you from there.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific... Can you post some code showing what you have so far? And be more detailed about exactly what you mean.

Comment: If, as I suspect, you are doing an incremental search then you might want to look into a `Trie` data structure. This allows for very fast discovery of all the strings in a collection that start with a specified prefix. See [this Visual Studio Magazine article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/10/20/text-pattern-search-trie-class-net.aspx) for details.

Comment: There is a String.StartWith function. Do you want to improve on it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adapted the code from [this article from Visual Studio Magazine](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/10/20/text-pattern-search-trie-class-net.aspx) that implements a `Trie`.

The following program demonstrates how to use a `Trie` to do fast prefix searching.

In order to run this program, you will need a text file called "words.txt" with a large list of words. [You can download one from Github here](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words.txt).

After you compile the program, copy the "words.txt" file into the same folder as the executable.

When you run the program, type a prefix (such as `prefix` ;)) and press `return`, and it will list all the words beginning with that prefix.

This should be a very fast lookup - see the Visual Studio Magazine article for more details!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var trie = new Trie();
            trie.InsertRange(File.ReadLines("words.txt"));

            Console.WriteLine("Type a prefix and press return.");

            while (true)
            {
                string prefix = Console.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
                    continue;

                var node = trie.Prefix(prefix);

                if (node.Depth == prefix.Length)
                {
                    foreach (var suffix in suffixes(node))
                        Console.WriteLine(prefix + suffix);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Prefix not found.");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> suffixes(Node parent)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            return suffixes(parent, sb).Select(suffix => suffix.TrimEnd('$'));
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> suffixes(Node parent, StringBuilder current)
        {
            if (parent.IsLeaf())
            {
                yield return current.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var child in parent.Children)
                {
                    current.Append(child.Value);

                    foreach (var value in suffixes(child, current))
                        yield return value;

                    --current.Length;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public char Value { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
        public Node Parent { get; set; }
        public int Depth { get; set; }

        public Node(char value, int depth, Node parent)
        {
            Value = value;
            Children = new List<Node>();
            Depth = depth;
            Parent = parent;
        }

        public bool IsLeaf()
        {
            return Children.Count == 0;
        }

        public Node FindChildNode(char c)
        {
            return Children.FirstOrDefault(child => child.Value == c);
        }

        public void DeleteChildNode(char c)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
                if (Children[i].Value == c)
                    Children.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    public class Trie
    {
        readonly Node _root;

        public Trie()
        {
            _root = new Node('^', 0, null);
        }

        public Node Prefix(string s)
        {
            var currentNode = _root;
            var result = currentNode;

            foreach (var c in s)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.FindChildNode(c);

                if (currentNode == null)
                    break;

                result = currentNode;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public bool Search(string s)
        {
            var prefix = Prefix(s);
            return prefix.Depth == s.Length && prefix.FindChildNode('$') != null;
        }

        public void InsertRange(IEnumerable<string> items)
        {
            foreach (string item in items)
                Insert(item);
        }

        public void Insert(string s)
        {
            var commonPrefix = Prefix(s);
            var current = commonPrefix;

            for (var i = current.Depth; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                var newNode = new Node(s[i], current.Depth + 1, current);
                current.Children.Add(newNode);
                current = newNode;
            }

            current.Children.Add(new Node('$', current.Depth + 1, current));
        }

        public void Delete(string s)
        {
            if (!Search(s))
                return;

            var node = Prefix(s).FindChildNode('$');

            while (node.IsLeaf())
            {
                var parent = node.Parent;
                parent.DeleteChildNode(node.Value);
                node = parent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

First, your million strings need to be ordered, so that you can "seek" to the first matching string and return strings until you no longer have a match...in order (seek via C# `List<string>.BinarySearch`, perhaps). That's how you touch the least number of strings possible.

Second, you should probably not try to hit the string list until there's a pause in input of at least 500 ms (give or take).

Third, your queries into the vastness should be async and cancelable, because it's certainly going to be the case that one effort will be superseded by the next keystroke.

Finally, any subsequent query should first check that the new search string is an append of the most recent search string...so that you can begin your subsequent seek from the last seek (saving lots of time).

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at seek and the subsequent query append. The other two are taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using linq.

```
string x = "searchterm";
List<string> y = new List<string>();
List<string> Matches = y.Where(xo => xo.StartsWith(x)).ToList();
```

Where x is your keystroke search text term, y is your collection of strings to search, and Matches is the matches from your collection.

I tested this with the first 1 million prime numbers, here is the code adapted from above:

```
        Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();
        SW.Start();
        string x = "2";
        List<string> y = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("primes1.txt").Split(' ').ToList();
        y.RemoveAll(xo => xo == " " || xo == "" || xo == "\r\r\n");
        List <string> Matches = y.Where(xo => xo.StartsWith(x)).ToList();
        SW.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("matches: " + Matches.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("time taken: " + SW.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Console.Read();
```

Result is:

> matches: 77025
>
> time taken: 0.4240604

Of course this is testing against numbers and I don't know whether linq converts the values before, or if numbers make any difference.

Comment: Given that OP seems to be wanting performance as well, it might be worth taking a per-character approach and successively refining a set of matching strings.

Comment: @hnefatl true, I'm not 100% on the way StartsWith goes about things, although I do think in terms of simplicity and speed taken loosely into account, that linq is a good way forward. If the OP could test this and return results with their data, it might help others refine this to work a lot faster :)

Comment: @Jaxi I have it currently implemented this way, as I just wanted to get something working but now I am looking for performance improvement

Comment: Just seen your code, are your results loaded from a db or from a file?

Comment: @Jaxi Loaded from a text file similar to yours. I will test and see if I see improvements

Comment: @Jaxi setting the data type seems to keep it closer to 300ms rather than fluctuating between 300-700ms

Comment: Ah, that's good I suppose :P I imagine it's because it doesn't have to figure out a data type at runtime.