# How To perform a partial search for a string

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I recently saw CS2 console and decided to improve my own console. I am trying to use a Dictionary to autocomplete all available commands i.e. typing "s" would display "survey","skills","slow"

Commands and Dictionary are added to a list.

```
 private void Awake()
    {
        devConsole = GetComponent<DevConsole>();
        CreateConsoleCommands();
    }
 
void CreateConsoleCommands()
    {
        AllCommands = new List<DevCommands>();
        SearchCommand = new Dictionary<string,DevCommands>();
 
        string CommandName = "help";
        DevCommands Help = new DevCommands(CommandName, "Shows all commands.", () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in AllCommands)
            {
                DefaultLog(item.Name + ": " + item.Description);
            }
 
        });
        AllCommands.Add(Help);
        SearchCommand.Add(CommandName, Help);
 
        CommandName = "clear";
        DevCommands Clear = new DevCommands(CommandName, "Clears the console", () =>
        {
            ConsoleLogText.text = string.Empty;
 
        });
        AllCommands.Add(Clear);
        SearchCommand.Add("clear", Clear);
 
        CommandName = "spawn";
        DevCommands Spawn = new DevCommands(CommandName, "spawns items ", () =>
        {
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("GAME"))
            {
 
                SpawnProps.SpawnAll();
 
                DefaultLog("Spawned more props.");
            }
            else
            {
                DefaultLog("Cannot be used in the main menu.", LogType.Warning);
            }
 
        });
        AllCommands.Add(Spawn);
        SearchCommand.Add(CommandName, Spawn);
```

I have tried a dictonary but that dosen't seem to include partial search.

```
 void SearchForDevCommand(string text)
    {
        if (SearchCommand.TryGetValue(ConsoleInputField.text,out DevCommands command))
        {
            Debug.Log(command.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Can't find any command.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a trie in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416050/how-to-create-a-trie-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510143/106159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SearchCommand` dictionary is only good for the final **exact** access!

As a simple solution for the search you rather want to use e.g. `StartsWith` and use it as a filter like e.g.

```
List<DevCommands> SearchForDevCommand(string text)
{
    return AllCommands.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();

    // basically same as doing

    //var results = new List<DevCommands>();
    //foreach(var c in AllCommands)
    //{
    //    if(c.Name.StartsWith(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    //    {
    //        results.Add(c);
    //    }
    //}
    //
    //return results;
}
```

See

- [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) (`using System.Linq;`)
- [`string.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith#system-string-startswith(system-string-system-stringcomparison))